# Angular2: how can I access an array of objects that are retrieved using an Http.get

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventService } from '../../app/event.service';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'map-view',
  templateUrl: 'mapview.html'
})
export class MapView
{

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  events: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private eventService: EventService)
  {

  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getEvents();
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap()
  {
    let center = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);
    let mapOptions =
    {
      zoom: 13,
      center: center,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  }

  getEvents()
  {

    this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(response =>
    {
      this.events = response.lexington;
      console.log(this.events[0]);
    })


  }
}
```

Basically what this is doing now is calling a service that retrieves json objects from a URL. I know that part is working fine. However, how can I make that response available to the rest of the file?

Comment: I assume that the `eventService.getEvents()` returns one or more JSON formatted messages. Any chance we can see what those look like? Can you add one to the question?

Comment: What do you need to achieve exactly? What needs to be "available to the res of the file"? Where does it need to be used in the file?

Comment: @R.Richards for sure: {"name":"John Doe Live","description":"Comedy","region":"NY","venue":"Comedy Bar","address":"123 main","geocode":[111.111, 111.111],"start":"1484935200","end":"1484946000"}

Comment: @JBNizet so the objects contain geocodes for locations. I'm trying to place them on the google map.

Comment: And what prevents you from doing it? What code did you try? You're already logging this.events[0] to the console. So instead of logging it, put it on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want to save the response?

**Edit**

From the comments, it looks like you want to use the response to populate google maps.

So just do after you get the events json object

Like:

```
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  events: any;
  eventsReponse:any; // this

  getEvents()
  {

    this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(response =>
    {
      this.eventsReponse = response;  

      // You have the response here, you can populate google maps 
      // here like

      this.populateGoogleMaps(response);
      ...
    })


 }
```

Comment: Ahh! I tried that earlier but thought it didn't work. I just forgot to add the "this." before the function! Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, your question was very misleading , it should have been that your function is not being called because you missed "this"